# YouTube Data API, 10,000 quota reached with just a few hundred PUT updates

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a YouTube channel with almost 800 videos. I'm using the YouTube Data API V3 to update the titles and descriptions of each video.

Here's a cURL example of the kind of update I'm doing:

```
curl --request PUT \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxx","snippet":{"description":"Updated description, often quite long","title":"Updated title","channelId":23}}' \
  --compressed
```

This is (finally) working great. So I set about doing a bulk update, where I generate the new titles and descriptions for each video and shoot off individual PUT request.

The trouble is, I got to about 175 successful updates before I got the warning:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
}
```

I've used my 10,000 daily request quota in under 200 updates. How is this possible?

Is there perhaps a way I can update multiple video IDs during one PUT request. How is the quota count tallied? I can't seem to find any data on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs' [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) says that invoking the `Videos.update` endpoint on `snippet` part has a quota cost of 53 units.

As a consequence, with a daily quota amounting to 10000 units -- if only accounting the updates -- you cannot get more than 188 of your videos' `snippet` metadata updated on any given day.